# tracking visitors to site get name of corporate network

Tags: web, google-analytics

Is there a way to track visitors on my site and provide me with reports on the visitors beyond just the city/state but precisely maybe the Corporation name / Hospital name if it was browsed from their corporate network? I'm assuming technically my analytic would give me the IP so theoretically I could find out a corporate network from that but is there any tool that can do this for me automatically and report it to me?

Comment: I doubt you can get that info very easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get ISP information, which includes a domain or corporation name in some cases.
See `visitors - network properties - network location` in GA.

And with [IPfingerprint](http://www.virtualnet.co.uk/ipfingerprint.html) tool, advises you instantly (automated) every time a company visits your website.

Hope it helps.